# how to build sql queries using c

Tags: c, string

I was wondering if it is possible to build a string with the following code

```
char query[512];
char *insert = "insert into tableName values("%s, "%s");"
strcpy(query, insert);
method("max", "1234"); //function which adds values inro %s
```

My questions, how can I add another char array into in place of %s if it is possible?
Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Instead of formatting strings, use *data binding*.

Comment: Thanks for your effort
I will try that as well
sprintf is also working )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use sprintf() so that you can replace the %s with char array
https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf

```
char query[512];
char *insert = "insert into tableName values(\'%s\',\'%s\');";
sprintf(query, insert, "max","234");
printf("%s",query);
```

This is actually a bad approach. This will introduce SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you very very much @jobinrjohnson sprintf that solved my problem)))

Comment: Nit - `insert` should be `const char *` (see prototype in linked man page) and there is no need to escape single-quotes within double-quotes, e.g. `const char *insert = "insert into tableName values('%s','%s');";` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks)))
it helped a lot ))